# Why do I get -38 error, while trying to insmod a kernel module probing do_fork?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, kernel-module, jprobe

I am trying to `insmod` a jprobe module to a rooted Android phone:

```
 #include <linux/kernel.h>
 #include <linux/module.h>
 #include <linux/kprobes.h>

 /*
  * Jumper probe for do_fork.
  * Mirror principle enables access to arguments of the probed routine
  * from the probe handler.
  */

 /* Proxy routine having the same arguments as actual do_fork() routine */
 static long jdo_fork(unsigned long clone_flags, unsigned long stack_start,
               struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long stack_size,
               int __user *parent_tidptr, int __user *child_tidptr)
 {
         printk(KERN_INFO "jprobe: clone_flags = 0x%lx, stack_size = 0x%lx,"
                         " regs = 0x%p\n",
                clone_flags, stack_size, regs);

         /* Always end with a call to jprobe_return(). */
         jprobe_return();
         return 0;
 }

 static struct jprobe my_jprobe = {
         .entry                  = jdo_fork,
         .kp = {
                 .symbol_name    = "do_fork",
         },
 };

 static int __init jprobe_init(void)
 {
         int ret;

         ret = register_jprobe(&my_jprobe);
         if (ret < 0) {
                 printk(KERN_INFO "register_jprobe failed, returned %d\n", ret);
                 return -1;
         }
         printk(KERN_INFO "Planted jprobe at %p, handler addr %p\n",
                my_jprobe.kp.addr, my_jprobe.entry);
         return 0;
 }

 static void __exit jprobe_exit(void)
 {
         unregister_jprobe(&my_jprobe);
         printk(KERN_INFO "jprobe at %p unregistered\n", my_jprobe.kp.addr);
 }

module_init(jprobe_init)
module_exit(jprobe_exit)
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

but it is failed:

```
  root@android:# insmod my_jprobe.ko
  [3223.32]register_jprobe failed, returned -38
```

I get `-38` error, and couldn't understand what is it, the only return value on failure I saw is `-22`, is it possible to insmod a jprobe module on arm based chip?

`do_fork` is in the `System.map` and is in the object table.

What flags do I need to turn on in the config file to support `jpobes`?

Comment: If I'm right to assume that `register_jprobe` returns standard error codes, -38 means ENOSYS or "Function not implemented".

Comment: @tangrs ,you are right register_jprobe and register_kprobe aren't in the system.map. how can I add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have register_probe or register_kprobe in your System.map, that means that CONFIG_KPROBES is not enabled in your current kernel config.

You would need to build kernel for your platform with it enabled and then try your module.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONFIG_OPTPROBES=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_OPTPROBES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
```

And one more config flag I needed specific to my platform:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_LOAD=y
```

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with Linux 4.17.0.

I found that jprobes has been abolished after 4.15:
https://lwn.net/Articles/735667/